# In Java catch block, how do you know which method/line throws the exception?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

In try block, I want to execute two functions. If the first one failed then don't execute the second. I also want to print out which function failed.

See following code.

```
try {
  a = func1();
  b = func2();  //won't execute if a failed
}
catch (Exception e) {
  //TODO: print a or b failed?
}
```

Does the language support this scenario naturally?

If not, is the following a good practice? (I cannot think of anything wrong about it. But it concerns me as I don't remember seeing any one using `return` in `catch`.)

```
try {
  a = func1();
}
catch {
  //print: a failed
  return; //if a failed then skip the execution of b
}

try {
  b = func2();
}
catch {
  //print: b failed
}
```

EDIT:
Summary of comments:

1. throw different exception from two methods.

   - In this case the methods are written by others and I have no control.
2. e.printStackTrace() will print line number and function

   - I want to do more than just printing. More like, if a failed, execute the following code.

Comment: `e.printStackTrace()` to get the stack trace. Or throw different exceptions from the two methods.

Comment: This doesn't even compile.

Comment: Use slf4j logger for logging your code. You will see in stacktrace class and method is thrown exception.

Comment: Use the second variant, without a `return` in the `catch` - generally a bad idea. Or, throw _different_ exceptions from your methods.

Comment: The stack trace already has the line number and the function which failed.  What do you want to do which it doesn't do already?

Answer (score 6):

What you want is  `String methodName = e.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName());`

But this is hardly a good practice. The standard way is to log the exception using appropriate method in your logging framework or (if writing a console app, which is rarely the case with Java) to print it to the error or standard output or optionally to other  `PrintStream`, for example using `printStackTrace(printStream)`.

But in most cases you want to propagate exception to the upper layers and handle (or decide to not handle it) by the appropriate high level code. Catching exceptions like this leads to nasty bugs. Returning from catch black is also a very bad idea in 99% of cases because exception signalizes abnormal termination of the method while returning a value does not.

Answer (score 2):

As dev-null wrote `e.getStackTrace()` can help. But note that the exception may not be thrown by `func1` or `func2` themselves but by some other method they call. So you need to go through all elements of the array until you hit `func1` or `func2`.

Calling them in separate try blocks is definitely practiced but it can get cumbersome.

Comment: So you mean the `return` in the `catch` won't hurt, right?

Comment: Hurt in what sense? I don't see a problem at least in your example.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
String failedFunc = "func1";
try {
    a = func1();
    failedFunc = "func2";
    b = func2();  //won't execute if func1() failed
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Func '" + failedFunc + "' failed: " + e);
}
```

Or course, if all you're doing is printing the error, then printing the stack trace will show you exactly where it failed. The above code is however useful if you need the value of `failedFunc` without a full stack trace.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Maybe, maybe not. If you're calling 10 functions, and want a single error handler that just needs to know how far it got before failing, this may be better (not repeating error handler). It all depends on why you want to know, and what you intend to do about it.

Comment: In this example, for logging, letting the logging framework deal with it would be neater I think. If you want to _handle_ the error then having each _method_ handle its own errors may be better. I don't see a role for this particular solution.

Answer (score 1):

Logging the stack trace if an exception is thrown will inform you which line threw the exception. If the first line in the try/catch throws the exception, the next line will not be executed.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, you can use `e.printStackTrace()` to determine the cause of the `Exception`. Since you expressed a desire for different *behaviors* then you have a few options. You could write two local functions to *decorate* your `func1` and `func2` calls with custom `Exception`s. Something like,

```
class Func1Exception extends Exception {
    public Func1Exception(Exception e) {
        super(e);
    }
}

class Func2Exception extends Exception {
    public Func2Exception(Exception e) {
        super(e);
    }
}
```

Then you can write the local functions like

```
private static Object func1Decorator() throws Func1Exception {
    try {
        return func1();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Func1Exception(e);
    }
}

private static Object func2Decorator() throws Func2Exception {
    try {
        return func2();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Func2Exception(e);
    }
}
```

Then you can handle them however you wish,

```
try {
    a = func1Decorator();
    b = func2Decorator(); // this still won't execute if a failed
} catch (Func1Exception e) {
    // a failed.
} catch (Func2Exception e) {
    // b failed.
}
```

If you want `func2` to run even when *a fails* you could use a `finally` block,

```
try {
    a = func1Decorator();
} catch (Func1Exception e) {
    // a failed.
} finally {
    try {
        b = func2Decorator(); // this will execute if a fails
    } catch (Func2Exception e) {
        // b failed.
    }
}
```